# Batch file for-loop with subrutine: Not forwarding parameter including spaces

Tags: batch-file, cmd, parameter-passing

My problem is that the for-loop in my batch-script is reading pdf-file-paths from the "allepdfsnamen.txt" but is not forwarding these file-paths (which are including space-characters) correctly to the subroutine:

[image]

- %%X is the parameter (pdf-file-path) which can include spaces
  e.g. "C:\Users\gruberw\Documents_OT_Tickets\20170320_I\Testpdfs\Scan Charge 31\0000000_134388_266737109_001.PDF"
- %1 the :body (subroutine) is only receiving file-path until first space-character-occurance
  [image]

I have tried to put the paths which are provided to the for-loop in the "allepdfsnamen.txt" under double-quotes:

[image]

I have tried to put the parameter given to :body (%%X) under quotes.

Can anyone tell me how to correctly (complete file-path with space-characters) hand over a parameter to a subrutine (:body) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to cut-and-paste so it can be copied and run easily.

```
for /f "delims=" %%x
```

turns off the default tokenising using space-delimiter.

```
call :body "%%x"
```

quotes the string to be passed to the subroutine

```
echo %~1
```

strips the quotes from the first parameter

Comment: using`delims=` in for loop and the  `echo %~1` in the subroutine cut away the first quote so the parameter is handed over including all space-characters - thank you very much.